# Ignore first "0" in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I'm currently working on my MIPS Assembler and sooner or later was confronted with a problem. Instructions like these:

```
JAL $000A2000
```

turned out (in hex) as:

```
0C 00 28 80
```

which is wrong, as this would mean:

```
JAL $0000A200
```

When I left out the zero in my instruction, like:

```
JAL $00A2000
```

it worked and the result was:
    0C 02 88 00

So, but I don't want to always ignore the "0" by hand. I want that ANTLR4 ignores the first value from left. As example, I like that ANTLR4 turns this:

```
JAL $000A2000
```

into this:

```
JAL $00A2000
```

I'm still new to ANTLR4 and have not yet an idea how I would accomplish this. I'm thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess what a lexer rule looked like for the token you mentioned, I would probably choose this:

```
Stuff : '$' [0-9a-fA-F]+ ;
```

This rule would match `$00A2000` and `$000A2000`, but it would also match `$f` and `$C083FFa0b88200`. All other validation would be performed in code, not as part of the grammar.

If you attempt to write lexer or parser rules more specifically than necessary, it will have a substantial negative impact on the ability of your code to accurately report and handle errors that occur in the input.

Comment: Yes, that's what I basically did. It matches 0-9a-fA-F with the dollar character. But I actually want that the first value ($02698D00 -> ignore that "0") is skipped/ignored, as it totally messes up the code. Of course, I could say now that everyone should write $xxxyyyy instead, but that wouldn't be right. The documentation of mips assembly wants it to be like $xxxxyyyy. So, I want that you write $xxxxyyyy, antlr4 ignores first 'x' from left (aka zero) and matches $xxxyyyy instead.